# SharePoint 2016 Server Web Application

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2016, web-application

We have SharePoint 2016 Farm with 2-front-end with Distributed cache, 2-Application with Search Service, 1-Search Database Server, 1-Content database server, 1-Office web app server. SharePoint foundation Web Application is running on all 4 SharePoint Server. Here my question in when I create Web Application, on which server IIS will be created? What is the best practice on Web Application Service. And please suggest best method to increase Performance.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1):

**In when I create Web Application, on which server IIS will be created?**

- In case the `SharePoint Foundation Web Application` is running on all 4 SharePoint Server. So the web application will be created on **all SharePoint servers cross the farm**!

**What is the best practice on Web Application Service?**

- Patch your farm to at least `November 2016 Public Update for SharePoint Server 2016 (Feature Pack 1)`
- Ensure that `SharePoint Foundation Web Application` is started on **all SharePoint web servers** on a farm.
- Stop it on application servers!

For more details check [Plan service deployment in SharePoint Server](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj219591(v=office.16).aspx)